# Solr Queries Have bad performance when using Group.facet=true

Tags: solr

I'm trying to use Solr Group Queries .
They work 0k, average time is about 120ms.
When I enable group.facet=true the queries become unbearably slow - about 8sec!!!

Can anyone help me out here, I really need to use both these features together.

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4763 ... No solutions yet it seems.

Comment: You might check out the [Collapse Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results). Depending on your needs it might work. It's supposed to be a faster way of doing grouping.